# awk filter produces unwanted lines

Tags: awk

> cat test.txt

produces:

```
1) Amit     Physics   80
2) Rahul    Maths     90
3) Shyam    Biology   87
4) Kedar    English   85
5) Hari     History   89
5) Deepak     Maths   98
```

Running:

```
awk '$4 == 80 END {print $0}' test.txt
```

results in

```
1) Amit     Physics   80
5) Deepak     Maths   98
```

**My question:**

The last line in the output has 98 in the 4th column. 98 is clearly not 80. But the awk query returns it. Why?

Comment: The code you posted cannot produce the output you say it does. If there was a semi-colon or a newline before END it could do that with some awks. It's important to post the actual script you're having problems with and not just something that kinda looks like it.

Comment: @EdMorton Please look at my screen shot https://drive.google.com/file/d/11X9nWvB_OseYH_-1GwbxWTVmHI3fZBbk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I stand corrected, you are apparently using a broken awk. There's only 2 valid interpretations of your script and those are 1) the uninitialized variable END is treated as a null string and concatenated uselessly with 80 before `== 80 END` is tested or 2) the awk symbol END is recognized as appearing out of context and a syntax error is printed. The awk you're running apparently recognized END as an awk symbol and terminated the rest of the script to let it treat it as if it had occurred in a valid position. I highly recommend getting a new awk as who knows what else might be wrong with it?

Comment: It looks like that bug exists in the awk on OSX (as do other bugs!). `awk '$4 == 80 END{print $0}' file` produces the output above while the same awk version running the equivalent code but using a regexp comparison instead of END for the condition `awk '$4 == 80 /98/{print $0}' file` outputs the expected/correct syntax error: `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 $4 == 80 >>>  /98/{ <<<
awk: bailing out at source line 1`. GNU awk and others correctly output the same syntax error for both cases.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your comments. I just installed gawk on my Mac and it returns syntax error on running the buggy query. Please write it as an answer, I will accept it as the verified answer.

Comment: Happy to help but the answer you already accepted is correct for the question asked so I'll just leave the comments here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's printing the last line because you told it to in the END block.  Just do:

```
awk '$4 == 80' test.txt
```

This evaluates each line and prints it if the statement `$4 == 80` is true.  In an END clause, $0 is assigned the value of the last line.  `END{print $0}` unconditionally prints the last line.